# Modern forum software with fluid categorization

Tags: self-hosted, forum

I need a good forum software for a new community site.

In particular, the software should:

- easy front end UX for new thread creation with full WYSIWYG editor and no need for users to enter code
- ability for users to upload images (ideally with resizing on server end to reduce space usage)
- threads can all be tagged or put into categories thus bypassing the traditional old forums structures and making it more fluid like Stack Exchange
- be least resource intensive and able to work on a shared server like GoDaddy
  -fairly easily customisable to add a logo, change basic colours
- work well on mobile phones (optionally having app versions)
- offer good long term support
- scalability: I'd also be happy to pay more if it scales significantly, but trying to keep it low cost while the audience is small, as it will be tiny in the first year

I'd like the product to be an open source platform, or at least one with a one off fee rather than something that locks me into an annual subscription.

Comment: Do you know [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mooSocial](https://moosocial.com/) which is interesting social media script. There are similar to this (even free). From their site:

mooSocial is a "white labeled" php social network software built using CakePHP. 
It is light, fast, easy to customize, and mobile-friendly.

Pricing for 2018:

mooSocial License: $99

Pro: $298

Deluxe: $398

Titanium: $1499

Open source alternative Elgg

> Elgg is an award-winning open source social networking engine that provides a robust framework on which to build all kinds of social environments, from a campus wide social network for your university, school or college or an internal collaborative platform for your organization through to a brand-building communications tool for your company and its clients.

Source: [10 top social network scripts in php](https://corpocrat.com/2011/06/02/10-top-social-network-scripts-in-php/)

Comment: Could you please include pricing information with your answer? ~USD150 for the simplest license might scare some folks off ;) Also, answers should show how each requirement is met (see our [answer guidelines](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185)). Could you address the ones you've skipped?

Comment: @Izzy I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it still lacks to show how the requirements OP listed (the bullte-list) are met by which of the licenses.